# Selecting a group of cells up in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a For Next Loop that take each cell in a range, selects say 10 below it, performs a calculation on those ten cells and puts the results in the next column. It would for example take cell A1, sum A1-A10 and put the results in B1.  It then loops to A2, sums A2- A11 and puts the results in B2.  The following code (only excerpt) works fine.

I want to sum UP rather than down.  Select cell A20, sum up A20-A10, and put the results in B20.  Haven't been able to do it.  In the following code the value for E1 would be 10 and is the number of cells selected down from each cell in range.

```
For Each Rng In Range("LogRd1")
    Rng.Select
    Selection.Resize((Range("E1").Value), 1).Select
    Rng.Offset(, 1).Formula = ((Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection)) / ((Range          ("E1").Value + 0.0001) - (Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection))))

Next Rng
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks,
Grant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED AGAIN:** a little more robust

```
Dim BLOCK_SIZE as Long
Dim Rng As Range, r as Range, s As Variant

BLOCK_SIZE = Range("E1").Value 

For Each Rng In Range("LogRd1")
If Rng.Row >= BLOCK_SIZE Then
    Set r = Rng.Offset(-(BLOCK_SIZE-1), 0).Resize(BLOCK_SIZE, 1)
    s = Application.Sum(r) 
    If Not IsError(s) Then
        Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = s / ((BLOCK_SIZE + 0.0001) - s)
    Else
        Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Sum Error!"
    End If
End If 'can offset to at least BLOCK_SIZE above this cell
Next Rng
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,I'll try working with that but I need to retain the E1.Value rather than just 10.  The User inputs a value in E1 that could be any integer.  When I try -E1, it doesn't work.  Similarly the Resize (11,1) would have to be in terms of the E1 Value.

Comment: Tim,  Crashes at Set r = ..... OK if I remove the negative and use positive 10.  Also I still have a question of how to use the E1.Value instead of a specific integer????

Comment: Well, it will crash if `Rng` isn't at least on or below row 10...  Made a few more edits.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  Now my only problem is that the BLOCK_SIZE value has to be the value in Cell E1 and it could be any integer.  I'll try just setting it as Long = Cell ("E1").Value ??  I appreciate the time you've spent here.  Thanks.

Comment: No, as Long= has to be a constant.  Won't accept Range("E1").Value.  Suggestions?

Comment: Wonderful.  That does it.  Thank you, Tim.  Always such a relief when it works.